# Does KornShell (ksh) have a Do...While loop?

Tags: shell, unix, scripting, ksh

I have a loop in my KornShell (ksh) script that I want to execute at least once, and I want an elegant way of doing it, however while I have found plenty of stuff on how to write a while loop, there does not seem to be anything for a do...while loop out there.

What I am doing is reading in a comma-delimited list of files from a configuration file and processing them. If the list of files is empty, then I want to process all files in the directory.

What is a good way to do this?

EDIT: Here is what I have currently. I grab the filename, then remove it from the string for the next pass. If the list of Files is empty, I quit the loop. BUT, if the list is empty to begin with, I want it to still run once.

```
  while [[ -n "${FILES%%,*}" ]]; do
       FILE="${FILES%%,*}"                             
       FILES="${FILES#*,}"
  done
```

Comment: have you tried to google first? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ksh-for-loop/

Comment: Sorry, no 'Do ... while' in ksh. Please consider editing your question to include your best pass at code so far. It is much easier to help when we can see what you're working with. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter, a normal while ... do ... loop can do this out of the box.  See my answer elsewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could fake it:

```
do_once=true
while $do_once || [[ other condition ]]; do
  : your stuff here

  do_once=false
done
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, the standard `while` loop in `ksh` supports this out of the box:

```
while ...; do ...; done
```

The standard `while` loop has code blocks *before* and *after* `do`.

Each block may contain multiple commands.  Conventionally we use only
a single command for the first block, and its exit status determines whether
the loop terminates or is continued.

When we use multiple commands, only
the status of the last command matters.

```
while
   echo do this always # replace with your code
   [[ -n "${FILES%%,*}" ]]
do
   FILE="${FILES%%,*}"                             
   FILES="${FILES#*,}"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such construct in ksh. You can emulate this by `break` (or `continue`) at the end of a `while true; do ... ; done` loop.

Comment: Perfect, I'm embarassed I didn't think of that.

Comment: Yet, the construct exists. `while block1; condition; do block2; done`.   `block1` is the code that always gets executed.  No need for a `break` or `continue`.